# How do I store/model data needed for my recommendation module?

Tags: data-mining, feature-selection, recommender-system, machine-learning-model

I'm reading data from a store's product catalog, a 100mb xml file which contains product-wise attributes like prices, categories, etc.

Given a `product_id`, my job is to find the products most similar to it. Let us say, I use the following attributes: `brand`, `color`, `price`, `category`to find similarity. Here's how I'm going about things:

1) I parse through the catalog, and save the mapping between each `product_id` and its `feature:value` pairs in `product_lists.json`.

```
[ { 123: 
      { 'brand' : 'abc',
        'color' : 'xyz',
        'category' : 'pqr',
        'price' : 123
      }
  },
  ...
]
```

2) I go through this `product_lists.json` and create `attributes.json` which basically lists all possible values of each attribute:

```
{ brand : [ 'a1', 'a2', ... ],
  price : [ 10, 1000, ... ],
  category: ['c1', 'c2', ... ],
  color : ['q1', 'q2', ... ]
}
```

3) I go through the `attributes.json` file and create `indexfile.json`, which maps each attribute value to a unique id:

```
[ { 'color1' : 1, 'color2' : 2, ... },
  { 'price_range_1' : 1, 'price_range_2' : 2, ... },
  { 'category1' : 1, 'category2' : 2, ... },
  { 'brand1' : 1, 'brand2' : 2, ... }
]
```

4) Then I refer to `indexfile.json` and `product_lists.json` and create a final `training.json` file by replacing values of attributes in the former with indices from the latter:

```
[ ["225845", [0], 6, [0, 1], [0]], 
  ["105016", [], 6, [2], [1]],
  ...
]
```

5) Lastly, I take in a `product_id`, go through `training.json` and find similar product matches using knns, simple `==` checks, Levenshtein distances, proximity et al depending on the features.

The problem is, this creates a lot of `.json` files which is obviously very ugly. Then there is the problem of redundancy - while it makes sense to use knns for price/size features, I don't really need to bin, index and then match categorical features like brand or model names.

I am primarily looking for suggestions as to how I can save the data for each step in a more optimal way instead of creating so many separate json files, and if there is a better method overall to perform the similarity check given the unpredictable nature of the features (categorical, discrete, continuous) and a possible need to add weights to the features while computing. I have to do this for about 20 stores, so a universal suggestion would be great.